# How to get notifications from the contents of Database in Android?

Tags: android, eclipse, intellij-idea, android-service, android-notifications

I have time (hours:min) values stored in my database. I want to pop a notification whenever the system time is equal to any value in the database. How to proceed ? I am new to android

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic way to do what you describe.

I suggest you sort the times in the DB to find the one that will occur next, and set an alarm (using the Alarm Manager) for that time.

That's probably a page of code, or so...